# XMLUnitException - Caught exception during comparison

Tags: xmlunit-2

```
Caught exception during comparison] Exception[org.xmlunit.XMLUnitException] follows: org.xmlunit.XMLUnitException: Caught exception during comparison   at org.xmlunit.diff.DOMDifferenceEngine.compare(DOMDifferenceEngine.java:88)    at org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder.build(DiffBuilder.java:386)
```

> Am getting the above error when i make continuous call for
>   comparison.During high volume it fails with the above error.Nothing wrong with the input.

Comment: The `XMLUnitException` wraps another exception as its cause. The inner one will tell you what has gone wrong.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` - This is the actual Error. But does not make sense. since it works later

Comment: if the stack trace of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` looks as if it was caused inside of XMLUnit (as opposed to inside the XML parser) we - the XMLUnit project - would appreciate a bug report.  ;-)